# Looping through an array without throwing exception

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

Say I have an array of values:

```
string[] text = new string[] { "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5" };
```

Then I have a basic loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + text[i])
}
```

Obviously, this will cause an out of bounds exception, so what I want to do is when the counter reaches the upper bound of the array then go back to the start.

So

```
0 = val1    
1 = val2    
2 = val3    
3 = val4    
4 = val5    
5 = val1    
6 = val2    
7 = val3    
etc..
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use the modulus operator:

```
Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + text[i % 5])
```

Comment: better to use text.Length, but +1 anyway ;-p

Comment: (should be text[i % 5], surely)

Comment: Thats great thanks, the name of the array was my fault I put string[i] in my post before editing.

Comment: Should be text[i % text.length] and you might want to change that 30 to be text.length * 6. That way in the future if you add an element you won't have to find those numbers and change them.

Comment: Fixed the array name, thanks. I don't even know C# (I do know C/C++) so I didn't pay much attention to the code (just copied and pasted it from the question).

Answer (score 12):

Take the modulus of the array length:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + text[i % text.Length]);
}
```

Comment: At least here you are using the Length property instead of hard-coding the length of the text array.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
for(int i=0;i<=30;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + string[i % 5])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + text[i % text.length])
```

?

Answer (score 2):

As a slightly less specific solution...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] text = new string[] { "val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5" };

        int count = 0;
        foreach (string t in text.ContinuousLoopTo(30))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(count.ToString() + " = " + t);
            count++;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ContinuousLoopTo<T>(this IList<T> list, int number)
    {
        int loops = number / list.Count;

        int i = 0;

        while (i < loops)
        {
            i++;

            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < number % list.Count; j++)
        {
            yield return list[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A little bit overengineered, but I like it :) +1

Comment: Absolutely, but overengineering can be fun :-P

Answer (score 1):

what? like forever?

```
bool run = true;
int i = 0;
string[] text = new string[] {"val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"};
while(run)
{
   Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + text[i])
   i++;
   if(i>=text.Length) i=0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The writeline should be:

```
Console.WriteLine(i + " = " + text[i%5]);
```

Comment: I know what you mean, I was beaten by about 30 seconds ;-)

Comment: lol - dayam - I'm off my game today!  I've already gotten my 200 pts for the day though so I shouldn't even jumping in here when it is obvious that 100 people are going to get this one in seconds.

Comment: I give up..."shouldn't *BE* jumping in here.  Man, I'm going to bed :-/