# Loop through an array changing the name of a variable as well

Tags: c#

I have an array of field names. I think that my question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463689/c-sharp-looping-through-an-array-without-throwing-exception) but I can´t seem to wrap my fingers around it. So I'm going to ask.I am creating a pivot table in excel. I have to add rowFields According to the array that is generated by the List object that is their data source. What I'm trying to do is I have a variables `rowField1` all the way to `rowField5`. I would like to try to do something like this:

.

```
// Please note this array can have anywhere from 1 string to 5 strings
string[] rowFields = { "Name", "EmployeeID", "Address", "Phone", "Pet_Name" }

for(int i = 0; i < rowFields.Length; i++;)
{
    rowField + i = rowfields[i];
}
```

Comment: You can't access variables in this fashion - the usual approach would be to store them in an array, but you've already got one.  This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: what you are trying to do is create a second array, `rowField2`, and copy the values from `rowField[i]` to `rowField2[i]`

Comment: @xanatos That's a bit of a stretch

Comment: @user3120232, it's likely because someone didn't understand your question, so downvoted you , voted to close your question and moved on. It happens...

Comment: @user3120232 Probably because your question shows a lack of basic understanding of C# computer programming. But be happy... It is asked at least once a month :-) And with my +1 you still have a net point gain :-)

Comment: @xanatos "Your question shows a lack of basic C# knowledge and is asked at least once a month, so I upvoted it" Seriously?

Comment: @Rawling Yes :-) The fact that it is asked at least once a month (and it probably is), shows that it is a point-of-passage in the life of a programmer. Before or later every programmer asks himself if it can be done... I don't see any big problem with that, and I do think that, being a point-of-passage (like becoming an adult), it should be rewarded :-) And in the end, being a common question, it is better if it is upvoted, so perhaps others will find it instead of reasking it.

Comment: Could you, please, post your *actual goal*, what do you want to do (trasnfrom, case etc.) with array?

Comment: @Rawling http://stackoverflow.com/q/30440931/613130 see? One month ago, nearly same question, see my comment? :-)

Comment: I will edit my post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create variables dynamically.

The best option you have to get this working is to use a `Dictionary<string, TValue>` to store the variable names and their values.

In your case, you would possibly need something like this (assuming that `rowField` is a `string`):

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d[rowField + i] = rowfields[i];
```

You can iterate over it using a `foreach` or access a member using the variable name.

Comment: Put somewhere that `rowField` is something like `string rowField = "Foo";`

Answer (score 0):

You can't create variables like that. You have to do it the long way:

```
string[] rowFields = {"Name","EmployeeID","Address","Phone","Pet_Name"}

var rowField1 = rowFields[0];
var rowField2 = rowFields.Length >= 2 ? rowFields[1] : "";
var rowField3 = rowFields.Length >= 3 ? rowFields[2] : "";
var rowField4 = rowFields.Length >= 4 ? rowFields[3] : "";
var rowField5 = rowFields.Length >= 5 ? rowFields[4] : "";
```

However, this is a lot of work to simply replicate the information already stored in the array, so stick with the array.